# Type mismatch on double array

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

Having some trouble dealing with a compile error. I have a class which runs some processes and updates some of its global variables. I also have another class which needs access to these variables so I've made a `Scripting.Dictionary` to hold `{key, value}` pairs.

This all works fine, I'm able to assign the variables in `class a` and use them in `class b` simply by referring to the `Dictionary` with it's key.

The problem I am having is: inside `class b` I make a function call which takes a `Double()` parameter in which I've referenced my `Dictionary` to pull the `Double().`

Here's the function call:

```
TransMatrix = BuildMatrix(i, Control_O(), Control(), Control_Surv(), ClassCoreVariables("All_ACM")())
```

***Note that `ClassCoreVariables(All_ACM)` is referring to my Dictionary.***

For completeness, here is the above functions declaration:

```
Public Function TransMatrix(Treat As Integer, OverS() As Integer, OverSur() As Integer, Survi() As Variant, ACM() As Double)
```

When I try to execute this code, I get the following error:

> Compile error: Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected

This is confusing me because, I've checked the type:

`Debug.Print TypeOf(ClassCoreVariables("All_ACM")()` 
`Returns: Double()`

I've also checked to make sure the array isn't empty (it isn't), and I've also tried to change the type to `Variant` after researching the web..

I'm unsure how to further proceed and would appreciate some help.

If I've missed any relevant information please ask and thanks in advance.

**Update** 
 
`Debug.Print TypeName(ClassCoreVariables("All_ACM")())`

is returning a run time error:

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: `ClassCoreVariables("All_ACM")` is not a `Double()` its a `Variant` containing one - anything in a Dictionary is stored like that. `TypeName` is resolving the type from the Variant  and showing you the underlying type but the runtime will not do this when you call the function.  You would need to pass `ACM As Variant`

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I've attempted to change the type in the function declaration to a `Variant` and still had no joy.

Comment: Works for me https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7a735cf0e15563c8a5a1b98a24be7899

Comment: @AlexK. ah, I was carrying the `ACM()` in the function declaration. I'm pretty sure it's working now, thanks for a speedy response. I'd be happy to confirm your answer if you'd like to write it out.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassCoreVariables("All_ACM")` is not a `Double()` its a `Variant` containing one  (anything in a Dictionary is stored like that).

`TypeName()` is resolving the type from the Variant and showing you the underlying type but the runtime will not do this when you call the function.

You would need to pass ACM As `Variant`:

```
Function BuildMatrix(ACM As Variant)
```